# How to design and print a custom 'application form paper' in WPF?

Tags: wpf, printing, custom-pages

It's actually a physical paper - an "insurance form" - in which the insurance customer fills in their information.
So far the customer had to write all the asked information in the blank fields on the paper, using a pen of course.
But I decided to develop an application in WPF by which the insurance company agent can easily "type" the desired information and then **print them on the same "insurance form".**

So I need to create a blank A4 page and put a number of 'text boxes' on specific places on the page. Let the user to adjust the size and the position of them on the page and fill in some text. Then print the page.

**The question** is, how do I do so ? I have no idea that what kinda tool in C# .NET and WPF there is that I can use. `System.Drawing` maybe ?

Answer (score 3):

Using Visual Studio, you would create a new WPF application, add a new [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx) to the project and inside (the XAML of) that `UserControl` in the visual studio designer you would then add a root layout panel like [StackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx) or [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) and on that panel you would add your [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label.aspx)s and [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx)es  ([CheckBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.checkbox.aspx), [RadioButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.aspx) etc.) that the user needs to fill out.

You would then place that UserControl into your main window (probaly inside a [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) because the whole page might not fit on the screen) together with a print button or menu entry.

You can then easily print out that whole `UserControl` using [PrintVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printvisual.aspx) in the click eventhandler of the button. You should be done pretty quickly if that is all what you need.

As an additional step you could go and style your controls and labels so that the look more like your paper form.

Comment: Awesome approach !
I'll definitely try it and will post feedback ;)
Thanks A LOT !

Answer (score 2):

The question is how your form looks. If you expect something designed - use ordinary objects create new window, and print the window without showing . 
Somthing like:

```
var window = new YourWindow();

window.Show();

PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();

pd.PrintVisual(window,"MyForm");

window.Close();
```

Expand, google [How to print wpf window](https://www.google.co.il/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=how+to+print+wpf+window&oq=how+to+print+wpf+window&gs_l=hp.3..0i30.787.5526.0.5981.11.9.0.2.2.1.367.1946.0j2j2j3.7.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.KD2dAvI-KdU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=b286b87b4dbd674d&bpcl=38625945&biw=1229&bih=789)

If you need more paged document (such as a Word document) you can use RichTextBlock. It has classes that allow you to layout. And then print it as any window, or you can print directly from RichTextBlock.

I have an app that does something similar, for me it's even more complicated, because the printed form changes frequently.

What I do is get the document as a Word, converts it to XAML using the [codeplex word add-in](http://wordtoxaml.codeplex.com/),
Makes some changes and so produces forms easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
I'll try to see if I can do anything good. And I'll feedback soon ;)

Thanks again